# Get function caller scope

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Is it possible to extract a functions caller scope?

I have this example:

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        var myId = function() {
            return this.id;
        }
        console.log(myId());
    }
}

myObject.printId(); // prints 'undefined'
```

The example above prints out `undefined`, because 'this' seems to be the window scope by default inside new functions (in this case myId). Is there any way I can use a proxy that applies the correct scope before executing?

Something like this (fictive):

```
var execute = function( fn ) {
    fn.apply(fn.caller.scope);
}

var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        var myId = function() {
            return this.id;
        }
        execute( myId );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Prototype library](http://prototypejs.org/) you could use Function#bind() like this:

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        var myId = function() {
            return this.id;
        }.bind(this);
        console.log(myId());
    }
}
```

A little overkill perhaps, but if you're using objects like this extensively it might be worth looking up.

Comment: Best answer so far. The prototype API describes my issue best at http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        var myId = function() {
            return this.id;
        }
        console.log(myId.apply(this));
    }
}

myObject.printId(); // prints '1'
```

The problem is that you want to run the function `myId` inside the scope of `printId`, not the scope of `myId`. You can create the function so that it gets the same scope by putting it inside `myObject`, instead of putting it inside `printId`:

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        this.myId = function() {
            return this.id;
        }
        console.log(this.myId());
    }
}

myObject.printId(); // prints '1'
```

### Answer to the comment:

`var` stores the variable in the function scope, which means `myId` is stored inside `printId`. This means that `this` in `myId` refers to `printId`, and not `myObject`. Since `printId` is stored in `myObject`, `this` in `printId` refers to `myObject`, and so `myId.apply(this)` inside `printId` changes the containing scope of `myId` from `printId` to `myObject`, and therefore `this` in `myId` now refers to `myObject`. In the second example `myId` is stored in `myObject` right away, and so `this` in `printId` and `myId` refer to the same object, namely `myObject`. Does that make any sense at all? :P

Comment: Good answer but you might want to drop the now incorrect comment at the end ;).

Comment: This doesn't solve it (maybe I didnt explain good enough). Why would I need apply() when I'm already in the correct scope (myObject)? See my fictive example.

Comment: I've tried to explain it in my answer. Tell me if that made it any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

`Function.bind()` is pretty well supported by the browsers now, as specified by [ECMAScript5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5). (Prototype updated to match the ES5 specs)

For those still finding this post.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
var myObject = {
  id: 1,
  printId: function() {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

?

If not that then:

```
var myObject = {
  id: 1,
  printId: function() {
    var myid = function() {
      return this.id;
    };
    return myid.apply(this);
  }
}
```

See [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply).

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    printId: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var myId = function() { 
            return _this.id;
        }
        console.log(myId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = (function()
{
  var id = 1;
  return {
    printId: function(){
     console.log(id);

};
})();


myObj.printId();
```